# Button inside table cell not clickable

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, xcode5

I have a custom cell which has two buttons that are connected to it's methods. I add the cell to the table like this:

```
BSOrderedItemCell *cell = (BSOrderedItemCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"OrderItemCell"];
if (cell == nil) {
    NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"OrderItemCell" owner:self options:nil];
    cell = (BSOrderedItemCell *)[nib objectAtIndex:0];
}
```

And after that I set it's properties.

The cell size is the same as table's heightForRowAtIndexPath: and none of the cells labels or buttons are outside that size.

The problem is that I can select the cell, but I can't tap on the buttons. It's as if I'm tapping on a label, nothing happens. So I end up with something like this: [image: Screenshot of UITableView]

EDIT: Just to clarify things. The problem is not the button click methods. It's that I can't physically click the button, like there is something in the way of it, or it's disabled by some control.

Comment: Where is the code for your custom BSOrderedItemCell class and where are the button actions ?

Comment: Did you check using the NSLog or Break point that whether the control is executing those methods or not?

Comment: Yes, I tried to log the methods, they are never called. The thing is it's not even clickable (it doesn't change color like regular buttons on click).

Comment: BSOrderedItemCell just has `- (IBAction)decreaseByOne:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"Decrease %@", name.text);
}` which is connected to the buttons and nothing else. And the increase method for the plus button

Comment: Do you see the log message displayed when you click the buttons. Is the IBAction invoked?

Comment: Well, no. That is the problem. To me it looks like the items are in the background, and tapping doesn't even reach them. Since when you add plain buttons (without IBActions) they still have that click animation, and this one doesn't.

Comment: you need to set the tag of button in your cell and then use that to do your setuff in target method

Comment: Tried it. The tag doesn't make a difference.

Comment: color blend layers on simulator to see if something is above your button

Comment: Can you make sure the button is above the labels in the xib file?  If you click them in interface builder, the label shouldn't highlight.

Comment: Here's the screenshot to show that they are not over each other. The buttons are "AAAAAA" and "+". And I can't click either of them. https://www.dropbox.com/s/14vpa37xdgkxjjr/Screenshot%202013-12-27%2011.35.59.png

Comment: Did you set userInteraction as disable for your cell? Did you connect that button with your cell via xib?

Comment: User Interaction Enabled for the xib is checked.

Comment: how big is the touch-area for the `+` or `-` buttons?

Comment: calling `[cell.contentView layoutSubviews]` fixed it for me

Comment: Has the issue been solved? I'm facing the same problem. @fruechtemuesli that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

you need to do following things

1. Set the tag of your button in yourcellxib. orderitemcell in your case
2. get the button

   UIButton  *btn =(UIButton*)[cell viewWithTag:];
       btn.tag=indexPath.row;

3.add method to your button

```
[btn addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:)  forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

now make a method

```
-(void)buttonClicked:(UIButton*)btn
{
NSLog(@"the button clicked is on cell number%d",btn.tag);

}
```

Comment: I already tried that. It's not the method that is the problem. The button "physically" can not be clicked. Like something doesn't allow it.

Comment: run on simulator-> from menu go to debug tab select color blend layers see if some view is above your button

Comment: I get something like this. So I guess that isn't it. https://www.dropbox.com/s/xtxe6o9yk0zovwv/Screenshot%202013-12-27%2011.17.41.png

Comment: Which one is your button  "- " or "+"

Comment: Both, they are tied to their IBActions which should just do NSLog. But the problem is I can't even get a button animation on click, so they're not even clicked when I tap them. They act kinda like a UILabel.

Comment: a suggestion just for testing make the - button really large and fill it with red color. You will be able to see then if its about surface area of button

Comment: Tested it with the large size and color blend layer. Even with the mouse I can't click it (so I guess I'm not missing the button).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this..

```
[cell.button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:)  forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

To avoid cell selection:

```
Cell's xib -> Selection -> Set as None
```

Comment: This won't fix the issue. The button isn't even selecting, doesn't matter if it has a target.

Answer (score -2):

Do not create IBOutlot for then in you cellForRowAtIndexpath add the method to button

```
[cell.button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:)  forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

and perform the selector there and if you do not required row did select delegate then add

`cell.userInteractionEnabled = NO;` //too

Comment: The thing is that I do require a row, and second problem is that the cell doesn't even click. It doesn't display the animation that a normal button does, so connecting it to a method isn't an issue here.

Comment: + and - are your buttons?

Comment: Yeah, just regular UIButtons.

Comment: I think you should try to add target at least a time as you can sure that why selector are not calling

Comment: Just tried it. That isn't it. It's like there is something in front of the button, or like the button is disabled.

Comment: try setEnable to button

Comment: @Mani I have set it to NO for not allowing cell to intractable

Comment: @Retro If you set NO to cell, you cann't access button , because it also subview of cell.