# UIButton not clickable in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uibutton

I added multiple buttons in my `UITableViewCell` wrapped with a toolbar, but all of them are not clickable, once I drag a button to the outside of the table view it's clickable already.

Here is the screenshot of my sample app and scene:

[image]

Button 1 is not clickable but button 2 is clickable, User Interaction Enabled has been ticked.

Comment: Plz provide your cellForRowAtIndexPath code...

Comment: @RamaniAshish but even I tried to create a new Table View Controller with just a button inside, and the cellForRowAtIndexPath just return `UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];`, the button inside is not clickable as well.

Comment: where is the IBAction of that button...?

Comment: I recommend you to create custom UITableViewCell and also dont forget to action of button as Ramani said.

Comment: @RamaniAshish I did tried to create IBAction with just NSLog, but nothing come out as well, if place the button to the outside of table view then it is working already.

Comment: @yucel-bayram I'm still new to iOS actually and I am using XIB to create my interface entirely, just not sure why the button cannot be click.

Comment: @RamaniAshish here is my screenshot in color blend mode: [link](http://i.imgur.com/haHzwyq.png), it's actually the same issue with this I guess: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20798475/button-inside-table-cell-not-clickable)

Comment: You better check this out if UIButton exist in your tableViewCell in runtime , this link can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14751949/check-if-uibutton-already-exists-on-uitableviewcell

Answer (score 1):

Okay found the issue already, was a mistake by my own, it's because I set the tableViewCell "User Interaction Enabled" to NO, cause I want to disable the Table View default row selection.

So I need to set each layers of view "User Interaction Enabled" to YES, then the button is now clickable, thanks for all the replies!

Answer (score 0):

**Create you button in `viewForHeaderInSection`, like this..**

```
-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    UIView *sectionView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 30)];
    UIButton *btn = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
    [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(btnClicked) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [sectionView addSubview:btn];

    //add other subviews to section viewww..

    //return
    return sectionView;
}

- (void) btnClicked
{
    //do your thing here..
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

cell.button.tag = indexPath.row
cell.button.addTarget(self, action: "btnClicked:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

}
```

Comment: keep on adding target , this will make your btnClicked call multiple times.